# File missing upon launching EC2 using Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've just launched an `t2.micro` free tier `EC2` instance and SSH into it from my local machine. And I was welcomed by an error message as below:

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
```

This instance was launch using the console and every option has been by default and nothing special being configured. What could be the reason for it?

Below is the `Locale` of this instance:

```
[root@ip-xxx .aws]# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Try adding this line `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 ` in `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: @IsaacLem: As you can see `LC_ALL` has not been set, you can do it by modifying the `/etc/environment` file to add `LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8`

Comment: Not quite understand how this `LC_ALL` works but wondering why wouldn't Amazon setting it instead of throwing an error? since it has been setting for all other variables?

Answer (score 3):

in my case it was required to add following lines to `/etc/environment`

```
LANG=en_US.utf-8
LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Also  for later use add the same two commands to `~/.bash_profile`

Based on @ardit comment